# Rewrite rule problem

Tags: rewrite-rules

My permalink is /%category%/%postname%.html

But I have to rewrite URL for posts.

This is my rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]', 'bottom' );
```

But after a flush, it returns 404 for domain.com/post-name

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just change your permalink settings?

Comment: Because it will break all existing URLs.